# how to find mean of specific values based on values of other columns

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a matrix like below.

```
2   1   0.020000000
2   1   0.020000000
2   1   0.020000000
2   1   0.020000000
2   2   0.434776340
2   2   0.392582120
2   2   0.549031660
2   3   0.0306320700000000
2   3   0.0336107500000000
3   1   0.0200000000000000
3   1   0.0200000000000000
3   1   0.0200000000000000
3   1   0.0200000000000000
3   1   0.0200000000000000
3   2   0.301534290000000
3   2   0.381151280000000
3   2   0.227146390000000
3   2   0.402937460000000
3   3   0.0773929900000000
3   3   0.0220243800000000
3   3   0.0859914800000000
```

I want to check the first columns values if it's 2 then check the next column and if its value is 1 calculate the mean of all values in column3 so it would be like this:

The mean of 3nd columns values and put the it in a different matrix.

```
    2   1   0.020000000
    2   1   0.020000000
    2   1   0.020000000
    2   1   0.020000000
```

Then try this process for 2   2, 2   3, 3   1 and so on.

The values of 2nd column is either 1,2 or 3 but the values of first column are in range of 2-5000.
  I tried like this but it doesn't work properly:

```
 [ii,jj]=find((S(:,2)==1)); //S is the matrix i mentioned earlier
      out=S(ii,[1,3]);
      for i=2:3
          if out(:,1)==i
              Mean(i) = mean (out(i,2));
          end
      end
```

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, they are, however in column1 prolly we don't have all values from 1-5000.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `unique` and `accumarray` function:

```
[unique_vals, ~, idx3]=unique(a(:,[1 2]),'rows'); % find unique combinations
means = accumarray(idx3, a(:,3),[],@mean); % find means
result = [unique_vals means]; % join groups and their means
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not really sure if I understand the question since you write that you want to compute the mean of the values in the third column, but also make a sub-matrix.

For now I assume that you want to compute the mean of all the values in column three that have 2 1 in the first two columns. The code would look something like this

```
mean21 = mean(S(S(:,1) == 2 & S(:,2) == 1,3))
```

You first compute a colum of booleans where col1 == 2 AND col2 == 1 `(S(:,1) == 2 & S(:,2) == 1)` and then retrieve the corresponding values of col3.

If you automatically want to do this for arbitrarily large matrices, the following would be one solution

```
for c1 = unique(S(:,2))'
    for c2 = unique(S(:,2))'
        mean_val(c1,c2) = mean(S(S(:,1) == c1 & S(:,2) == c2,3));
    end
end
```

However, this will give you NaNs if the combination c1, c2 does not exist.

Comment: Well, the sub-matrix was for more explanations. yes i can use it like this but not for 5000 values.

Comment: Fair enough. So by 5000, you mean 5000 different values in column 1 and 2?

Comment: I mean numbers of 1-5000 for column1 and numbers 1,2,3 for column 2.

Comment: I changed the above answer, no it is done in a loop.